# How to inherit DataTemplate in another DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

OK, So I don't know if this is possible but? I'm trying to populate a DataGrid (Telerik RadGridView to be exact) and want to dynamically determine the edit controls. I'm trying to create a grid to display data that is being imported into the application and show three columns (Property Name, Inbound Data and Current Database Data). Based on a property in my object class the "Property Name" column needs to have a CheckBox placed in front of it. This follows with the other columns as far as conditionally appending a button so a lookup can occur (a TextBox or TextBlock would be in front of the button to display the current value). I hope this explains what I'm attempting to do. Below is the XAML I've come up with.

Oh This going into a WPF MVVM C# application.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
<UserControl x:Class="PulseHL7Importer.Views.DetailView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:p="clr-namespace:PulseHL7Importer.Properties"
         xmlns:fw="clr-namespace:PulseHL7Importer.Framework"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PulseHL7Importer.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="961">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <telerik:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanVisibilityConverter" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AddCheckBox">
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasCheckBox}" Value="True" />
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Margin="2,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AddTextBlock">
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Value="True" />
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AddTextBox">
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Value="False" />
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AddButton">
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasLookup}" Value="True" />
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <Button Content="..." Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ConditionalTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource AddCheckBox}" />
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource AddTextBlock}" />
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource AddTextBox}" />
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource AddButton}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:DetailViewModel}">
    <telerik:RadDockPanel Width="Auto">
        <!-- Toolbar -->
        <telerik:RadDockPanel telerik:RadDockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <telerik:RadToolBar OverflowButtonVisibility="Collapsed" />
        </telerik:RadDockPanel>

        <!-- Warnings and Errors -->
        <telerik:RadDockPanel telerik:RadDockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <telerik:GroupBox Header="Warnings and Errors"
                              telerik:Theming.Theme="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=SelectedTheme}">
                <TextBox Height="60" IsReadOnly="True"
                         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                         Background="FloralWhite" />
            </telerik:GroupBox>
        </telerik:RadDockPanel>

        <!-- Grid Area -->
        <telerik:RadDockPanel Width="Auto">
            <telerik:RadGridView Name="DetailGridView" Width="Auto" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
                                 CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserInsertRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                                 CanUserSortColumns="False" IsFilteringAllowed="False" ColumnWidth="*"
                                 ShowGroupPanel="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Properties}" >
                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}">
                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ConditionalTemplate}" Content="{Binding Path=Properties}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ConditionalTemplate}" Content="{Binding Path=Properties}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Client Data" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ClientData.Value}">
                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ConditionalTemplate}" Content="{Binding Path=ClientData}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Pulse Data" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PulseData.Value}">
                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ConditionalTemplate}" Content="{Binding Path=PulseData}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            </telerik:RadGridView>
        </telerik:RadDockPanel>
    </telerik:RadDockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've managed to solve this with a bit of a hack. I'm now dynamically creating the DataTemplate in the CellEditTemplateSelector. This allows me to check all the properties and add the controls and binding for the appropriate cells.

Here is the basic XAML grid:

```
                <telerik:RadGridView Name="DetailGridView" Width="Auto" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
                                 CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserInsertRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                                 CanUserSortColumns="False" IsFilteringAllowed="False" ColumnWidth="*"
                                 ShowGroupPanel="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Properties}">
                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Name" IsReadOnlyBinding="{Binding Path=IsReadOnly}"
                                                DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}"
                                                CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CellTemplateSelector}"
                                                CellEditTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CellEditTemplateSelector}">
                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsReadOnly}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Background" Value="LightGoldenrodYellow" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsGroupItem}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Background"  Value="LightGray" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsRequired}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Red" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellStyle>
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                    <telerik:GridViewMaskedTextBoxColumn Header="Client Data"
                                                DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ClientData.Value}"
                                                CellEditTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CellEditTemplateSelector}">
                        <telerik:GridViewMaskedTextBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ClientData.IsReadOnly}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Background" Value="LightGoldenrodYellow" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsGroupItem}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Background"  Value="LightGray" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </telerik:GridViewMaskedTextBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                    </telerik:GridViewMaskedTextBoxColumn>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Pulse Data"
                                                DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PulseData.Value}" 
                                                CellEditTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CellEditTemplateSelector}">
                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PulseData.IsReadOnly}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Background" Value="LightGoldenrodYellow" />
                                   </DataTrigger>
                                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsGroupItem}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Background"  Value="LightGray" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellStyle>
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Here is the CellEditTemplateSelector:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;
using Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace PulseHL7Importer.Framework
{
public class CellEditTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)container;

        if (element != null && item != null && item is Property)
        {
            GridViewCell cell = (GridViewCell)container;
            Property property = (Property)item;
            Column column = null;
            StringBuilder grid = new StringBuilder();
            BrushConverter converter = new BrushConverter();

            #region Control Header

            grid.Append("<DataTemplate");
            grid.Append(" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"");
            grid.Append(" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\"");
            grid.Append(" xmlns:mc=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006\"");
            grid.Append(" xmlns:d=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008\"");
            grid.Append(" xmlns:telerik=\"http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation\"");
            grid.Append(" mc:Ignorable=\"d\"");
            grid.Append(">");

            #endregion  //Control Header

            switch (cell.Column.Header.ToString().Replace(" ", "").ToUpper())
            {
                case "NAME":
                    grid.Append("<StackPanel Orientation=\"Horizontal\"");
                    if (property.IsGroupItem)
                        grid.Append(" Background=\"LightGray\">");
                    else
                        grid.Append(">");
                    if (property.HasCheckBox)
                    {
                        grid.Append("<Grid Width=\"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=StackPanel, AncestorLevel=1}," +
                            " Path=ActualWidth}\">");
                        grid.Append("<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>");
                        grid.Append("<ColumnDefinition Width=\"Auto\" />");
                        grid.Append("<ColumnDefinition Width=\"*\" />");
                        grid.Append("</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>");
                    }
                    if (property.HasCheckBox)
                        grid.Append("<CheckBox Grid.Column=\"0\" IsChecked=\"{Binding Path=IsChecked}\" Margin=\"3,2,3,0\" />");
                    if (property.IsReadOnly)
                        grid.AppendFormat("<TextBlock{0} Text=\"{{Binding Path=Value}}\"", property.HasCheckBox ? " Grid.Column=\"1\"" : "");
                    else
                        grid.AppendFormat("<TextBox{0} Text=\"{{Binding Path=Value}}\"", property.HasCheckBox ? " Grid.Column=\"1\"" : "");
                    if (!property.HasCheckBox)
                    {
                        grid.Append(" Margin=\"15,0,0,0\" ");
                        grid.Append(" Width=\"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=StackPanel, AncestorLevel=1}," +
                            " Path=ActualWidth}\"");
                    }
                    if(!property.IsReadOnly)
                        grid.Append(" BorderBrush=\"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=StackPanel, AncestorLevel=1}," +
                            " Path=BorderBrush}\"");
                    grid.Append(" Background=\"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=StackPanel, AncestorLevel=1}," +
                        " Path=Background}\" />");
                    if (property.HasCheckBox)
                        grid.Append("</Grid>");
                    grid.Append("</StackPanel>");
                    break;
                case "CLIENTDATA":
                    column = property.ClientData;

                    grid.Append(this.BuildColumn(property, "ClientData", column));
                    break;
                case "PULSEDATA":
                    column = property.PulseData;

                    grid.Append(this.BuildColumn(property, "PulseData", column));
                    break;
            }

            #region Control Footer

            grid.Append("</DataTemplate>");

            #endregion

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(grid.ToString()))
            {
                return (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(grid.ToString());
            }
        }

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }

    string BuildColumn(Property property, string columnName, Column column)
    {
        StringBuilder grid = new StringBuilder();

        try
        {
            grid.Append("<StackPanel Orientation=\"Horizontal\"");
            if (property.IsGroupItem)
                grid.Append(" Background=\"LightGray\">");
            else if (column.IsReadOnly)
                grid.Append(" Background=\"LightGoldenrodYellow\">");
            else
                grid.Append(">");
            if (column.Options != null && column.Options.Count > 0)
            {
                grid.Append("<telerik:RadComboBox SelectedValue=\"{Binding Path=ClientData.Value}\"" +
                    " ItemsSource=\"{Binding Path=" + columnName + ".Options}\"" +
                    " IsReadOnly=\"{Binding Path=" + columnName + ".IsReadOnly}\"" +
                    " Width=\"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=StackPanel, AncestorLevel=1}," +
                    " Path=ActualWidth}\" />");
            }
            else
            {
                grid.Append("<Grid Width=\"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=StackPanel, AncestorLevel=1}," +
                    " Path=ActualWidth}\">");
                grid.Append("<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>");
                if (column.HasCheckBox)
                    grid.Append("<ColumnDefinition width=\"Auto\" />");
                grid.Append("<ColumnDefinition Width=\"*\" />");
                if (column.HasButton)
                    grid.Append("<ColumnDefinition Width=\"21\" />");
                grid.Append("</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>");
                if (column.HasCheckBox)
                    grid.Append("<CheckBox Grid.Column=\"0\"" +
                        " IsChecked=\"{Binding Path=" + columnName + ".IsChecked}\" Margin=\"3,2,3,0\" />");
                if (column.IsReadOnly)
                {
                    grid.AppendFormat("<TextBlock{0} Text=\"{{Binding Path=" + columnName + ".Value}}\"",
                        column.HasCheckBox ? " Grid.Column=\"1\"" : " Grid.Column=\"0\"");
                    if (property.IsGroupItem)
                        grid.Append(" Margin=\"4,3,3,0\"");
                    else
                        grid.Append(" Margin=\"4,0,0,0\"");
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(column.Mask))
                {
                    grid.AppendFormat("<telerik:RadMaskedTextBox{0} Value=\"{{Binding Path=" + columnName + ".Value}}\"" +
                        " Mask=\"{{Binding Path=" + columnName + ".Mask}}\"",
                        column.HasCheckBox ? " Grid.Column=\"1\"" : " Grid.Column=\"0\"");
                }
                else
                    grid.AppendFormat("<TextBox{0} Text=\"{{Binding Path=" + columnName + ".Value}}\"",
                        column.HasCheckBox ? " Grid.Column=\"1\"" : " Grid.Column=\"0\"");
                if (!property.IsReadOnly)
                    grid.Append(" BorderBrush=\"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=StackPanel, AncestorLevel=1}," +
                        " Path=BorderBrush}\"");
                grid.Append(" Background=\"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=StackPanel, AncestorLevel=1}," +
                    " Path=Background}\" />");
                if (column.HasButton)
                    grid.AppendFormat("<Button Grid.Column=\"{0}\" Content=\"...\" />",
                        column.HasCheckBox ? "2" : "1");
                grid.Append("</Grid>");
            }
            grid.Append("</StackPanel>");

            return grid.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            grid.Clear();
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually `ContentPresenters` get the respective implicit template, so you just need to bind the `Content` of one to the property or DataContext you want templated and it should be templated.

*(Not sure if this applies to your problem as i did not quite understand what you wanted to say)*

Comment: Well I think it has more to do with displaying one or more of the controls conditionally. Basically this is working with the exception that all the different controls (CheckBox, TextBox and Button) display. So I guess the real question is how do I get only certain controls to display?

Comment: @dhamilton: Well, you usually distinguish by type and select an appropriate control/template. Could use a `ContentTemplateSelector` for this.

Comment: Well I've been trying to rework this a little and think I have a reasonable solution close at hand. I believe it brings me down to solving bindings between my grid and the data templates that get selected. Basically I have a class "Properties", this class has some properties that control the first column of my grid. It also has some properties (ClientData and PusleData) that are sub-classes; which are used in my last two columns. My problem is that in the template selector and the template itself bind to "Properties" and not to "ClientData" and "PulseData". Here's the code.

Comment: Sorry not enough space to post all my code. So here is grid binding (ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Properties}"), and each column (DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" / DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ClientData.Value}" / DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PulseData.Value}"). Then one of the data templates i have (other follow this same pattern) 
<CheckBox Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Margin="2,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}" />

Comment: So how do I get the correct DataContext in the template selector and in the data template once it's been selected? In the case of the last two columns it would need to be "ClientData" and "PulseData".

Comment: @dhamilton: Maybe you should not dig that deep with your bindings then, i.e. bind to ClientData instead of ClientData.Value, then only bind the Value inside the templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the DataType property of your DataTemplate to the different classes used by your different viewmodels.

If the same viewmodel class must conditionally return a different templates depending on an internal value, you can declare your template in App.xaml

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AddCheckBox">
     ...
</DataTemplate>
```

Then reference it in the viewmodel by using

```
public DataTemplate ConditionalTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.ConditionMet)
                return Application.Current.Resources["AddCheckBox"] as DataTemplate;
            else
                return Application.Current.Resources["DifferentTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps